# Вставка массива в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Есть массив данных price, полученный с помощью serialize
Выглядит так: `s:6:"5443.7";s:4:"5443";s:6:"5442.3";s:6:"5442.2";s:6:"5441.9";s:6:"5441.4";s:6:"5441.3";s:6:"5440.9";s:6:"5439.7";s:6:"5439.6";s:6:"5439.4";s:6:"5439.3";s:6:"5439.2";s:4:"5439";s:6:"5438.1";s:6:"5437.7";s:6:"5437.5";s:4:"5437";s:6:"5436.7";s:6:"5436.6";s:6:"5436.2";s:4:"5436";s:6:"5435.5";s:6:"5435.4";s:6:"5435.1";`

Теперь пытаюсь вставить его в БД, поле имеет тип varchar

```
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE book SET ask='$price' WHERE coin='123' ");
```

Но вставляется только конечно значение s:6:"5435.1";
Как вставить весь массив?

Comment: Вставлять сериализованные данные плохая идея. Уж лучше json хранить.

Comment: В прошлом твоем вопросе я написал ответ как хранить данные. Но ты уже второй раз не можешь задать вопрос правильно, соответсвенно, непонятно для чего ты хочешь хранить эти данные и как затем использовать.

Comment: @Dodik периодически мне нужно будет доставать данные из БД и использовать в таблице

Comment: @Dodik проблема даже не в типе хранимых данных, а в том, что вставляется только последнее значение массива, хотя запрос на вставку находится внутри цикла foreach

Comment: @Bertly запакуй в json и сохраняй и все. А последнее значение у тебя сохраняется потому что UPDATE, а не INSERT

Comment: Похоже вы что то не так сериализовали. Вы пробовали перед update распечатать текст полученного запроса ? не может update положить в БД только часть переданного значения. Если в БД оказывается `s:6:"5435.1";` то и передали вы в update ровно это. Надо в единственный update передать единственную строку, которая содержит все сериализованные данные целиком.

Comment: @Mike в этом то и проблема, что прямо перед апдейтом я вывожу данные, которые хочу занести и они представлены в полной мере, но в БД записывает только последнее значение

Comment: @Bertly Этого не может быть. Покажите весь код, который печатает значение и заносит его в БД. обратите внимание, никаких циклов в программе в этом месте быть не должно в принципе. Заносится должно строго одно значение в одну запись, один раз (каждый последующий update одной и той же записи затирает предыдущее значение)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте записать массив в json строку с помощью json_encode($array) и в таком виде его записать а далее после получение его с бд просто используйте json_decode($content)